# How to make canvas gradient as a button background on hover

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas, hover

I have an `<a>` button,

```
a {
position: relative;
display: inline-block;
color: #111;
padding: 10px 20px;
border-radius: 10px;
background: #fff;
margin-top: 10px;
}
```

and there is a cool gradient as a background on a website https://sealzi.com/ (it's made with `<canvas>` element)

How can I make a gradient (like on the website) as a background of my button on hover?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add `a:hover` and write `background` you like.
For example;

```
a:hover{
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, red,orange,yellow,green,blue,indigo,violet);
    }
```

Also you can change `color` of button text of your own choice.For more details please do check [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_gradients.asp).Hope this will be helpful.